# expressing union of sets using set differences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, summation

How to prove the following equality

> Let A, B and C be sets. Prove that
> $\hspace{1cm}A \cup B \cup C\:= (A -B) \cup (B-C) \cup (C-A) \cup (A \cap B \cap C).$
> using a chain of if and only if statements.

I tried to express set equality formula using propositional variables and connectives, solve it and then use in the solution of above equality, but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the De Morgan's laws we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}(A-B)+ABC=\sum_{cyc}(A(-B)+ABC)=\sum_{cyc}A(-B+BC)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}A(-B+B)(-B+C)=\sum_{cyc}A(-B+C)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(A(-B)+AC)=\sum_{cyc}(A(-B)+AB)=\sum_{cyc}A(-B+B)=\sum_{cyc}A.$$
I used the cyclic summation.

For example, $$\sum_{cyc}(A\setminus B)=(A\setminus B)+(B\setminus C)+(C\setminus A)=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus C)\cup(C\setminus A),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(A(-B)+ABC)=$$
$$=((A\cap\overline{B})\cup (A\cap B\cap C))\cup((B\cap\overline{C})\cup (B\cap C\cap A))\cup((C\cap\overline{A})\cup (C\cap A\cap B)).$$

Comment: I have a question that is about summation symbol. What is cyc below summation symbol. What do you mean by using summation like that? Can you just provide sample extended version of one of the summations in your answer?

Comment: @Imral I added something. See now. Sometimes thinking by cyclic summation gives very easy solutions, like you see.

Comment: thank you very much. I appreciate your work. What a beautiful solution this is.

Comment: @Imral  You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Oh I see you wanted if and only if statements. I guess need to say $x\in A\cup B\cup C \iff x\in A\vee x\in B\vee x\in C \iff \ldots$. But the idea can be the same.

Here is a similar proof for only two sets:
$$
\begin{split}
(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) \cup (A\cap B)
&= (A\cap B^c) \cup (B\cap A^c) \cup (A\cap B) \\
&= (A \cap (B \cup B^c)) \cup (B\cap A^c) \\
&= A \cup (B\cap A^c) \\
&= (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c) \\
&= A\cup B
\end{split}
$$
Line 2 is distributivity in reverse; line 4 is distributivity.